# Using .htaccess to mirror main domain in subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to mirror all files from the same domain into my subdomain but exclude some files (e.g. robots.txt) to avoid SE-indexing.
So the subdomain should show and behave exactly the same as the main domain, including all files and query strings.

**Server folder configuration:**

/htdocs/domain
/htdocs/subdomain

**Domain configuration:**

domain.com
subdomain.domain.com

How to achieve this using a .htaccess file in the subdomain folder?

Comment: Do you want to redirect your traffic coming from the subdomain to your domain using URL rewriting?

Comment: I don't want to redirect in the sense that the user gets forwarded to the main domain. For the user it should seem as if he's still on the subdomain. But see the same contents...

Comment: You don't need to maintain separate folder if the only reason is to have few files unreachable over subdomain.

Comment: @JanPaepke Why don't you write the rule such that if the request comes from a particular sub domain, make these files unreachable? That way you won't need 2 separate folders, just point both the domains to the same folder.

Comment: @DusanBajic there may be other differences later as well.

Comment: @gaganshera I'm not sure how I would approach this. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this with a combination of .htaccess and PHP.

I used .htaccess and modrewrite to push the complete request into a php file that I placed in the subdirectory's folder.

In that PHP file I included the main domains file if no local version existed.

```
$mainpath = "../domain/";
$localFile = $_REQUEST["__PATHREQUEST"];
$replacementFile = $mainpath . $_REQUEST["__PATHREQUEST"];

unset($_REQUEST["__PATHREQUEST"]);

if (file_exists($localFile)) {
    include($localFile);
} else {
    include($replacementFile);
}
```

maybe this helps someone...